# Jmeter: set property for each loop

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I'm trying to create a test that will loop depending on the number of files stored in one folder then output results base on their filename. I'm thinking to use their filename as the name of their result, so for this, I created something like this in BS preProcessor:

```
props.setProperty("filename", vars.get("current_tc"));
```

Then use it for the name of the result:

```
C:\\TEST\\Results\\${__property(filename)}
```

"`current_tc`" is the output variable name of a `ForEach` controller. It returns different value on each loop. `e.g loop1 = test1.csv, loop2 = test2.csv ...`

I'm expecting that the result name will be test1.csv, test2.csv .... but the actual result is just test1.csv and the result of the other file is also in there. I'm new to **Jmeter**. Please tell me if I'm doing an obvious mistake.

[Test Plan Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCUdJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way of setting the property seems okayish, the question is where and how you are trying to use this `C:\\TEST\\Results\\${__property(filename)}` line so a snapshot of your test plan would be very useful.

In the meantime I would recommend the following:

1. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries, if something goes wrong - most probably you will be able to figure out the reason using this file. Normally it is located in JMeter's "bin" folder
2. Use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to check your `${current_tc}` variable value, maybe it is the case of the variable not being incremented. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about troubleshooting tecnhiques

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for the quick answer. I am really expecting a day or two before someone will answer my question :). Anyway, I uploaded a screenshot of the test plan. I am using C:\\TEST\\Results\\${__property(filename)} as a filename in view result tree. I use debug sampler and found that the current_tc is changing value in each loop.

Comment: You won't be able to use listeners this way, they are initialised **before** any scripting pre-processors

Comment: I see. So this is impossible to accomplish in my current set up?

Comment: I would suggest keeping single .jtl file, once your test is finished you will be able to split it into several lesser files using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) if needed. You can install the tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I'm going to do now